# Using 2 menu templates on WordPress

Tags: wordpress, menu, navigation

I want to use 2 menu template on WordPress. First is a default template, and the second is a mega menu plugin.

To call the mega menu plugin template, use code like this:

```
 <?php do_action('mega_menu'); ?>
```

The scenario is: when the plugin is not installed, then the default menu will display.
I use this code:

```
 <?php if(function_exists('main_nav')) { ?>
 <?php do_action('mega_menu'); ?>
 <?php } else if(function_exists('main_nav')) { ?>    
 <?php main_nav(); ?>   
 <?php } ?>
```

But unfortunately did not work.
Really appreciate for any helps. Thanks in advance.

Comment: and what is the problem, didnt work is not enough to describe it?

Answer (score 1):

```
add_action('mega_menu','my_mega_menu'); // Add action hook `mega_menu` to your callback funciton `my_mega_menu`

function my_mega_menu(){ // callback function 

 wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'your mega menu name' )); // calling menu in callback fn

}

<?php if(function_exists('main_nav')) { ?>
 <?php do_action('mega_menu'); ?> // calling hook `mega_menu` 
 <?php } else if(function_exists('main_nav')) { ?>    
 <?php main_nav(); ?>   
 <?php } ?>
```